# Find $p,q $ prime numbers s.t. $p+p^2+...+p^{10}-q=2017$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, prime-numbers

> Find $p,q $ prime numbers s.t. $$p+p^2+\cdots+p^{10}-q=2017.$$

It's easy to see that $p=2; q=29$ is solution.

There exists another solutions?

Comment: $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{10} p^k = \frac{p^{11} -1}{p-1} - 1$$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee ... $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{10} p^k = \frac{p^{11} -1}{p-1}$ .... - 1.

Comment: oh right, the $1$, oops edit:fixed

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's the same thing as fleablood's correction, right?

Comment: Oh, I misswed the $-1$, because the $dots$ make it look like he is starting something else. @ZubinMukerjee

Comment: Wait yours should be $p^{n+1}$ so it's not the same thing (and I think it's not right?)

Comment: For other aspiring parity users: note there are eleven terms on the left hand side, so LHS is only even when $q$ is even.

Comment: To demonstrate that this is anything but trivial:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{10}47^k\right)-2017=15121231\cdot3554114849.$$ The two factors on the right are both primes. So we cannot show the existence of an obvious factor unless your definition of obvious is different from mine :-)

Comment: Problemcausing, WHAT IS THE SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM?

Comment: @Will Jagy A  children asked me to solve it. But it looks  too difficult.

Comment: Yes, my use of dots there was .... pausing for dramatic effect.  :P

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this is easily solvable.

Comment: By brute force, solution for $2 \le p \le 1000$, $$ \begin{array}{r:l}p & q\\ \hline
2 & 29\\
197 & 88485562579618578299669\\
359 & 35657911907044503284516183\\
509 & 1169585279068041551153627933\\
677 & 20254832663971728368620344629\\
761 & 65225532325322091475061743793\\
971 & 745829908017344846102009009843\\
?& ???
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 5):

Here are the first 250 solutions.  Probably worth recording: I am using GMP mpz_probab_prime_p . The skeptical site of Nicely checks with number of repetitions (of Miller Rabin) up to about 12. Knuth recommends that 25 is enough. I am using 50 repetitions. In case of doubt, there are sites where one may get proofs that numbers really are prime, [I think one is called primo.](http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html)

===============================================================================

```
int mp_PrimeQ( mpz_class  i)
{
  if ( i <= 0 ) return 0;
  else if ( i == 1 ) return 1;
  else return  mpz_probab_prime_p( i.get_mpz_t() , 50 );
} // mp_PrimeQ
```

================================================================================

```
Wed Feb 21 15:52:24 PST 2018
2     29
197     88485562579618578299669
359     35657911907044503284516183
509     1169585279068041551153627933
677     20254832663971728368620344629
761     65225532325322091475061743793
971     745829908017344846102009009843
1217     7132844981760581967399318965609
1877     543092949534195418989542687985029
1979     921886486722572279659693314558083
2027     1171525630819127265272756951522579
2927     46171674464284277755743138375632879
3539     308267940127175729695490142165190283
3779     594133249509777096291724896102549083
4451     3052625488490934250424997128501405243
4547     3778723068058427991176196436472950619
4937     8604373387897811952339591499539770849
4967     9141743775431903705411979504636054359
5471     24029599705635538001589942488643457343
5879     49329700686922746494337283851961288583
6197     83538187551840060520258231309529621669
6389     113343563325496986192790171946710338533
8999     3483299208892505464466718878972024952983
9011     3530027556240796466745530647109449360043
9059     3722635717014895421816581082114644122683
9281     4742360046974006378568062013375894524393
9857     8659476286786531283677905362825995582889
10037     10377255579054111055157908278999253808549
10487     16089927776559223118404380634716314488199
12527     95171177864396428966390118010924913876079
14621     446478423053323490581360634105297147588093
14699     470876965338909026363497521163481792174483
15569     836825840014935299878602388534949639132633
15629     869640386478708123265415859281601866552333
16091     1163743689821493129500535602988079989609443
16829     1822253996386854131773220882090062877546333
16931     1935761057517107713205761674564582489067643
17351     2473262020697604169247578260461463505914743
17669     2965816572218928602083609379212963362322133
19031     6232164577319783739602920131294810337023143
19301     7174978582339164904466519897959756471909493
19727     8925498093631485955435182682578080258838479
21557     21672218171424595596431749749078938013722789
21569     21793161640816606103876328313166466596102633
22229     29459053978458916796227270868982198586019333
22469     32798710646721854246002397466937082247898133
23459     50479316506377083382640296410520628616850683
23741     56886389895414185385947747747998469155097693
25169     102018013586926625291785614001010783202284633
25307     107751620970082738738322550696849855028461539
25349     109553295682712640606360067556915926376683733
26489     170087355520439341363983311505065544807338033
26921     199953040679241595084585465393090379087694593
27437     241758672183234408791046297110900719192378349
27767     272461563026034407035369211355852296290173959
28541     358679926717624054950513949516469468237921693
28607     367061082813965451137135149236590857259276639
28649     372485896474429236567105024477766513684167233
29021     423778283009684819687239777878378958053020093
30497     695961857171782126153853225947757734928245769
30809     770531004588040803880301775778354524759076433
32057     1146152272570550862111665449635636239378866289
33641     1856529608289024959811629362460042434046272193
33647     1859843448232171591751631267800605911788302319
34439     2347026185209837980087530560193139772560185783
34871     2658621259323480010562372665911829134163414343
34949     2718691717252190294706528537637960308608635733
35279     2986585649365862991223724481326697932956141583
35831     3488200263094750484074824314073519540031467143
35951     3606798089800300082708021711483121865319637743
35999     3655244504826896015093012561130814112399817983
36467     4159223707045654370836839837334506463654474859
36479     4172930488350943310385178261955252746168135583
36857     4626063711719593356910744763594636842276051889
37337     5265090368423526711799460139069618936351805649
37511     5515666497935173746320430841691438015575727543
37781     5925786265845665931012609157823465498037741893
38501     7157005939206300500318604459298328605823365493
38747     7627672465355403870885940102408029346938226019
40277     11235229107559744851418805598237960358911997829
40289     11268747819551267353150462229634422449044569033
40829     12873542421332061815040581954723189382377426333
41039     13551216384776054263972419376510335948108752783
42209     17949854004599888136097893535726123780818319433
43721     25521770585851443117633708932428171134454698593
44519     30581850468963603748871293977459013175413575383
45281     36238455956789399377393966694644665238414904393
45707     39795748070530621173667628642216380640122820339
45869     41228941892086505012842880393070358775356081133
46187     44178091047569288556002786456512808446613822099
48311     69257890756964776917986027878350649333479161543
48479     71704347305712687286036250418747671385928075583
50147     100567633113558357484088553368709600709979237819
50591     109835118686469624329586683940002496437821906943
52709     165522107658094946609748085536567751811829266933
53267     183903727998310769321522687876649030897135152459
53927     208003509095743578050406675706496936778860249879
54251     220843938713727529658505991737028216013577044243
55259     265483829355901545503903185156283299778046291683
56891     355175753275791764211382449365130592245134013443
57839     419001198746603318169597429869686703706041468783
58601     477592702590211005173901367843579851704286620993
59207     529343879567639605017586582884842341419216654839
60041     608816484007495368143651897109245656027948204193
60167     621714210306780639111056536182793912993578920759
60887     700249640967283825588649666090291328946725128999
62687     937091054058022145611889916589153278215720817599
62939     975450608932806298156616159372127551718677293283
63281     1029769911014036718352279708722427353234055094393
63299     1032702793400454085228752963046139796563581931483
64709     1287222419626186646624259138967106704964163206933
64997     1345673809742569363913034196366283947875089697269
66191     1614343632252828101626146962958462347712274084943
66467     1682934860734718688512799542232156971334223684859
66569     1708940154048220443013006907714703721779648377633
67121     1856054191703619055575261640617598209520473225593
67547     1977275030236775887007539399334634626997275131619
67967     2103717403417552295907205820537379344667961395359
70481     3025009445399175713032283136610729245842088770393
70709     3124302633882236245703255302173576376984230176933
71861     3672303850602526691737164640467825013987452384293
72161     3828524655803013510428598874867195279022932990793
74177     5043110720939165575274072559711316850476259969129
74471     5246596773700405252991462455246678888616819152343
74747     5444317921093324347685930519663932056044908958019
75269     5836698119232161305155746745542016506217445234133
75797     6259301889320608432473882051438364042210759836869
77699     8019732515559753825966342481905410495443621859483
78311     8674276139440767602701181841795077647528459811543
79829     10510232669535362444869669819114597351586889731333
84347     18226427560511780969744914520608919192777312033219
84701     19005990368928032559094116906855295512095519506493
84719     19046419025838640725040138853693374786988406774383
85121     19969733665420917690607663520411499436087827015593
86711     24029622952194961555879730009173749853610932793543
86729     24079551678958102149366105216314678947815158196833
88379     29073394850961957697919308719961483585799442126083
89261     32108672112579828339609845653191354144964805661293
89669     33606873257866759405013274578540383282527125962133
90971     38818116694382098410779321335646026960873872959843
91097     39359132518223069789908347736897269738624415157969
91229     39933180807776805797335887249528111521600543174333
91457     40942491058111064378968266924936624890406872058089
92381     45272167915951544149810583616974323579240947384893
92387     45301580037128263327239789576214067706558018829499
92567     46191980261946677171509952333213075426466263827559
94529     56971182067160965246872610774027156312848933657833
96731     71723465402278657263355959717811637294327977276643
96989     73659589398299203813545758863539884177769674985533
97151     74899207577498484616265394643772888933531596803743
98621     87035899610449881658277456028906862441448658608093
101429     115245962474213044429842366957769661078881215623333
101747     118910552765261070729355688148374077917403800007019
101939     121173582979366146600481213358472626758554071098283
104327     152746530306248132361572147418126434617271806186679
104759     159190661302646215555660331440155424140479208794183
105509     170961840625160298255851240641693885408328850602933
106367     185384400855918389916889575521341361825411200064159
109937     257894907522757620158426921027831395345844531105849
112361     320744946349197246366482563302399327512256830761793
112877     335782788561922423010224973631450487880629625322029
113027     340271713508774502891016971888107546015629550759579
115211     412043655635117295874041908829576253390113717661043
115781     432889162713979874092655467631784523211903295231893
116447     458444506854864455053936735657299595384548469225919
117779     513667766281546171463292270466348457389634411979083
117839     516290541867077613663953695857848102256971801168783
119099     574228570052064251837489744373900583486626649652483
119429     590339163258083534444949254056057628611287000533333
119447     591229508638193398923189853165081390615051520386919
119849     611431445931987715939795211903417428821745023711233
119921     615114599739299327584662352210122109220095632609593
121487     700328260845194829483576739288945276785500852485199
122021     731727467246276551352937543672022468543988106935093
123701     838949106195366280585257809781170585291670475651493
124121     867872960835372416203683077540642974126422688560593
127031     1094209769289162625287278516799713152244464928163143
127289     1116637370043076159446408003188147710632576583634033
127877     1169304948766250948999305328163365822881757359827029
129491     1325559422837179552461670977632792179152867838626443
129581     1334801306454798460159689037792051307481449066310893
131861     1589157506175323457031899914221960412210593803684293
132761     1701016088472609896899662584601908999607299038603793
133499     1797973881636079657296283510221567140747144305580483
135851     2141073582302362840957945272274017499542136167932243
136739     2285215552175267819608983402475623803409314901724283
137447     2406333465053574302681837993007052976398413741352919
138191     2539807131179521159405975807289070613899998224444943
139109     2713659846505988205467929982199527621943488281634933
139367     2764411123564254279243196875828666009519921075395159
140321     2959578102774460309485414442248170794244301521571593
141707     3265247487930417885932092357314726466287519394532339
142391     3426324174880546173873833018555640760737893336815943
142619     3481584297884398578655155248125743139410593917534883
144461     3958304269305315200009815446702048380657532208857293
145139     4148052621848728202402418970716710809336886178082283
145577     4274946034843980880342766468847524072424592884012929
145949     4385450490611025286390790537296876398794985330580733
146141     4443485010280626537035663712942600866640166768709693
147347     4824095840856503487226688025290380457586003426614219
148817     5327560273919536156828219680792982804904819860158809
149417     5546295830190516956713015899242806630605069839483009
151631     6425143852502435789648558955264415563478597570656143
152219     6678693271779081245647627314899604564291649472686883
152381     6750112998669751750049428295267511349719904794684893
152501     6803458858420835622749989510266092324358993539635493
152531     6816854469422055337844224773957463641898682671765643
152597     6846408406340705952923456039190815462772867877558469
152879     6973987644456058475344255685931818616123683355553583
153719     7366790693488194216102104620232734370447625939429383
154211     7606000512528932269810641284781958706775590930506043
154229     7614883137910294613912999886823854706435648995359333
154667     7833925300721772377880651739710056011330430082082259
154937     7971760252533400687071189066479075787819335848820849
155219     8118047901246274386590393225727276254286811118671883
155717     8382297496166702213984696356567239019931096581897109
156041     8558349772898748439688156728838950068293267236684193
156437     8778040189742720391015823968909209463634141406161349
157127     9172990647049754297211459851411874785570554556924279
158129     9775027577948598072637170021134956575901629978339833
158537     10030188550256413904420947373664482235033449163118049
160217     11145220510651641447510097142290630994741129010278609
160481     11330235194826693731572309548174351155129685929720393
160649     11449406335168104302855876029993073685134492673507233
161471     12048917717876725511303288011725861705410503707637343
161627     12165831766286087111204503885687298713009827932775779
162059     12494941499091854394895322584076688783054798669357683
162209     12611076107692685698832388155808896326614181157719433
164117     14175498568107190593217652879094669565083673567955909
164387     14410443273329644388048695301797548354108055417573499
165569     15480781486619409856873816319625000190973093563382633
165617     15525720287011664273567040702064799479250450230516409
166679     16550513306841790882055880561070291733832525312484583
167381     17260929407751785299478863670378303798763631381509893
169079     19094103588516413445610103341944074207183975256472583
169859     19993470509235360264502810104604943998081953168918683
171161     21579962665459598542613849774133686197951229618635793
171317     21777455848306871323899958215485905141699782270566309
172031     22702289793587115804993806747184935593203472866138143
172439     23246494668714305254702864801409650422440167607495783
173249     24361827965392848215336105466546609003665258356944233
174077     25551501763475077527659959113303888204251890534022429
175229     27293693089705286125810733659466867403863262712754333
176489     29321007190036582114736298203626185664419779831588033
177431     30924127132759178314148900625173939028470576725095143
179351     34438200204616781994347829510450673024358326855824743
179519     34762149495297500118856063768285527532238999307900383
183581     43479013102137779762307723662102036282625866372880893
184241     45067677608041956108954566408092428910346517092275193
```

Comment: Interesting that none of the $p$ found is $\equiv 3\bmod 10$. I wonder if there's another congruence condition at play or if this is just the strong law of small numbers at work. (Though it seems _very_ strong for coincidence.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki you seem to have a point,  I am asking for $3 \pmod{10}$ and running much higher and getting nothing

Comment: Oh! Of course, it's actually easy. If $p\equiv 3\bmod 5$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{10}p^i\equiv 2\bmod 5$, which would force $5\mid q$. It's a result of $2017$'s congruence class.

Comment: There are probably similar restrictions to be had modulo various small primes, but $p=5$ is the quick one to be picked out visually.

Comment: In case you were concerned, all numbers pass ECPP (Perl/ntheory and ecpp-dj) and APR-CL (Pari/GP).

Comment: @DanaJ Thank you, that is very nice of you.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**:

LHS is odd only when $q$ is odd. Consider the two cases:

- $p$ is even
- $p$ is odd

For the first case, $p=2$, forcing $q=29$.

For the second case, $p=2a+1$ and $q=2b+1$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, so we solve $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}p^i\right)-q=2017$$ giving $$\frac{p^{11}-p}{p-1}=2016-2b\implies (2a+1)^{11}-2a-1=2a(2016-2b)$$ or $$(2a+1)^{11}=2a(2017-2b)+1\implies c=2017-2b$$ where $$\begin{align}c&=1024a^{10}+5632a^9+14080a^8+21120a^7+21120a^6+14784a^5+7392a^4+2640a^3+660a^2+110a+11\\&=2d+11\end{align}$$ This means that $$b+d=1003$$ where $$\begin{align}d&=a(512a^9+2816a^8+7040a^7+10560a^6+10560a^5+7392a^4+3696a^3+21320a^2+330a+55)\end{align}$$

Comment: No, the LHS is odd unless q is even.

Comment: The exponent on $p$ should be $11$, not $10$

Comment: Left side is always odd if $q$ is odd

Comment: No matter what $p$ is, there are ten terms in $1 + p + p^2 + \cdots p^9 = p^0 + p^1 + p^2 + \cdots p^9,$ so this is ***even*** . Therefore $p + p^2 + \cdots p^{10} = p (1 + p + p^2 + \cdots p^9)$ is even

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong, so everything falls apart.

Comment: Have provided a partial answer. As has been said in a comment this problem is harder than it looks.

Comment: I don't know, my rule is that diophantine equations asking for prime roots are either **really** hard, or fairly simple. :) This one didn't look simple.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I put the first 250 solutions in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Some observations. Having established the case $p=2$ and $q=29$ assume without loss of generality that both $p$ and $q$ are odd primes.

**Observation 1:**
Notice that all odd primes can be written in either of the following ways: (i) $6n+1$ or (ii) $6n+5$ for some positive integer $n$.

First we show that $p\equiv q\equiv 5\mod{6}$ i.e. $p$ and $q$ can both be written in the form of (ii). Assume otherwise. Let $p\equiv 1\mod{6}$ then 
$$p+p^2+...+p^{10}-q=2017\Rightarrow 1+1^2+...+1^{10}-q\equiv 1\mod{6}\Rightarrow q\equiv 3\mod{6}$$
But it is impossible that the prime $q$ be expressed as $q=6n+3$ since otherwise $q\equiv 0\mod{3}$ contradicting that $q$ is prime. Hence $p\equiv 5\mod{6}$ equivalently $p\equiv -1\mod{6}$. Therefore
$$p+p^2+...+p^{10}-q=2017\Rightarrow (-1)+(-1)^2+...+(-1)^{10}-q\equiv 1\mod{6}\\\Rightarrow q\equiv 5\mod{6}$$
Establishing our claim.

**Observation 2:**
All primes can be written as: (i) $4n+1$ or (ii) $4n+3$ for some positive integer $n$. Next we show that $p\equiv q\mod{4}$. Suppose otherwise. First say $p\equiv 1\mod{4}, q\equiv -1\mod{4}$. Then we get 
$$p+p^2+...p^{10}-q\equiv 1+1^2+...+1^{10}-(-1)\equiv 3\mod{4}$$
but $2017\equiv 1\mod{4}$ hence a contradiction. Similarly for $p\equiv -1,q\equiv 1\mod{4}$ yields
$$p+p^2+...p^{10}-q\equiv (-1)+(-1)^2+...+(-1)^{10}-1\equiv 3\mod{4}$$
again a contradiction. Therefore $p\equiv q \mod{4}$.

**Observation 3:**
From observation 1 and 2 it follows that $p\equiv q\equiv 5\mod{12}$ or $p\equiv q\equiv 11\mod{12}$.

**Observation 4:**
The given equation is equivalent to 
$$p^{11}-1-q(p-1)=2018(p-1)$$
By Fermat's little theorem we have $p^{11}\equiv p\mod{11}$ since $11$ is prime. Therefore we have
$$p^{11}-1-q(p-1)\equiv p-1-q(p-1)\equiv(p-1)(1-q)\mod{11}$$
On the other hand $2018\equiv 5\mod{11}$ hence the main equation is equivalent to 
$$(p-1)(1-q)\equiv 5(p-1)\mod{11}\Rightarrow q\equiv -4\equiv 7\mod{11}$$
From Observation 3 we have $q\equiv 11\mod{12}$ then follows by Chinese remainder theorem that $q\equiv 95\mod{132}$. In other words $q=132N+95$ for some positive integer $N$. Note that we can apply Chinese remainder theorem since $\gcd{(11,12)}=1$. Similarly for the other case when $q\equiv 5\mod{12}$ we obtain $q\equiv 29\mod{132}$ or equivalently $q=132 N+29$ for some positive integer $N$. These observations agree also with the evidence in the comments above. We might conjecture that the pair of primes $(p,q)$ that solve the equation are of form: (i) $(p,q)=(12M+5,132N+29)$ or (ii) $(p,q)=(12M+11,132N+95)$ where $M,N\in\mathbb{N}$.